# How to convert AJAX String response to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, ejb

My EjB response using AJAX likes this:

```
"{'Active':{'123','456','789'},'Inactive':{'111','222','333'}}"
```

I want to convert the above string to JSON objects.
JSON objects will be used in JavaScript to draw the map.

Or

I want the same string to get converted like below in JavaScript:

var active = ["123", "456", "789"];
var inactive = ["111", "222", "333"];

Note: I'm using AJAX in JS.

Comment: [There ain't no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/), you just want an object. Also, the response string you show is not valid JSON, all of the single-quote characters would need to be double-quotes - if you fix that you can use the `JSON.parse()` method.

Comment: Response is just a string in that format. Needs to be converted as JSON

Comment: My point is don't invent your own, non-standard data transmission format, fix your EJB so that it responds with a string that is valid JSON so then your JS can just use `JSON.parse()`. So fix the quote characters like I already said, and also I just noticed that the inner `{` and `}` seem to be defining arrays so they should be `[` and `]`.

Answer (score 8):

```
var jsonString = JSON.parse(response);
```

`response` is what you get from ajax req (a json string), and jsonString is what you wanted

Comment: Note that the response string shown in the question isn't valid JSON.

Comment: Then it will be a parse error, it will only work if the response is JSON type string.

Answer (score -1):

```
let JSON_Str = "{'Active':{'123','456','789'},'Inactive':{'111','222','333'}}"

Obj = JSON.parse(JSON_Str)
```

Comment: This'll give a parse error, given the string isn't JSON.

Comment: Posting just 2 line of code and not explaining how this code will help OP to solve the problem is not very useful. Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) and try to post more detailed answers.

Comment: `how this code will help OP` - the answer is *not one bit*